# changing menu item color with jQuery

Tags: jquery, menu, colors, html-lists

I want to change the color of menu items, but my jquery code doesn't work how I expected.
Here is the code:

```
    $('#menu').find('li').each(function(x, li){
        $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");
        $(this).css('background-color', 'black').css('border-radius', '10px');
        console.log("Menu Item: "+$(this).text()+" "+$(this).css("color"));
    });

    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "#F2F2F2");
    $(this).css("color", "#c60c28");
```

and here is the regarding html:

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.supermarktcheck.de/lidl/sortiment">LIDL</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.supermarktcheck.de/aldi-sued/sortiment">Aldi</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.supermarktcheck.de/penny-markt/sortiment">Penny</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.supermarktcheck.de/rewe/sortiment">REWE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Einkaufskorb</a></li>
        </ul>           
    </div>
    <!-- end #menu -->
```

Can anyboby show me my mistake?

Comment: Why are you doing this with javascript in the first place ? I mean, you're setting CSS properties on each items, you could aswell do it in your CSS...

Comment: I want the active item in other color.

Comment: the best way to achieve this would be to define common style in the css together with the style of your active items (let's say, in an ".active" css class), then your JS should just take care of giving this class to the active item, and the style of all other items aren't using JS. Also, it would help if you explained what the expected behaviour would be and what you're getting now.